# Table headers that don't scroll beyond top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a long table on a page (after a header section). When a user scrolls down, I want to keep the table header at the top of the page (i.e. scroll up to the top and stay there).

I've found some scripts that do this, however so far I've not found one that works in IE7.

https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/

http://jsfiddle.net/trepmal/e7GN8/

http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/

Anyone found a solution to this? I don't want to give the table itself a fixed height and then a scroll bar for the table - the whole page scroll bar should still be used.

Comment: if it's just one table per page and its on top, you can just give it a fixed position via CSS. THough I doubt this is your scenario?

Comment: @PoeHah That won't work - the table header would just stay where it is and not scroll to the top, also the table content would just scroll above the table header. See the examples to see the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: I figured. Can't help much. Maybe this helps? http://datawebcontrols.com/demos/ScrollableDataGridFixedHeader.aspx
You can see if the resulting html works in IE7

Comment: @PoeHaH thanks, however this requires the table to have a height and introduces a scroll bar on the table only rather than the whole page.

Comment: Ach, this would be much easier if [`background-image: element(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element) had decent support.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
    var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {

        if ($window.scrollTop() > 1665) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'relative',
                top: 1187
            });
        } else {
            if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'relative'
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        }
    });
};

$('#page-header').followTo(460);
```

The line:

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > 1665)
```

Is useful to drop the element if required when you continue scrolling down a page, if you dont need this then you can remove it.
The rest of the function is a check to see where on the page the scroller is at on the page (to allow for your inital page header) so it knows when to 'pick up' the table head. the point in which this is picked up at is here:

```
$('#page-header').followTo(460);
```

Further to that, this function will also 'drop' the header back into position when the user scrolls back up.

EDIT: To ensure your content doesn't 'jump' up when the header is picked up, make sure you wrap the #page-header element in a container (such as #page-header-container) and give it a fixed height and width.

I would point you to my source for this but i can't seem to find it unfortunately, that said its pretty straight forward.

Comment: How do you use this with a table's <theader> section?

Comment: are your table columns a fixed width? If so I would recommend breaking your head out and into a ul instead and use the instruction above. I have made a slgith edit however, as to avoid the content 'jumping' up when the #page-header element gets its fixed position, you need to wrap it in a container element that has a fixed height and width, see edited answer.

Comment: The columns aren't fixed width. Tried this in jsfiddle and at least for me, the element gets fixed to the top of the screen, even if I put in a `<div style="height:300px;">&nbsp;</div>` before. Thanks for this solution, however I don't think it quite fits!

Comment: maybe I have misunderstood the question, can you elaborate further on what the problem with this solution is? Re reading the question it seems you are looking to fix the position of an element so it stays with you as you scroll down a page, is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is [this plugin](http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/) but it only makes a table body scrollable (the header and footer stay in place, but the table body gets a scrollbar and becomes scrollable if it goes beyond a given height), it doesn't make the header stick to the top of the page.

The way it works is the following : It saves the columns widths in a variable, then it extracts the header and footer from the table, puts them in a container before and after the table, then it puts the table itself in a container with the wanted max-height. This way if the table is bigger than the container's max-height, it becomes scrollable. Then it restores the column widths.

I think you can either adapt this plugin to fit your situation or create your own following this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this although it's just not suited because the table has a fixed height. The table will be positioned on a page however when scrolling, the table should occupy the whole height available in the browser, for various different resolutions.

Comment: Yeah, but I think you could adopt the same strategy (without limiting the height and making the body scrollable) to extract the table header in order to make it stick to the top of your page : once the header is an independent element, you can use an exisiting plugin like [this one](https://github.com/sdbondi/JQuery-StickToTop) to make it stick to the top.

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid is a very nice grid (table).
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example12-fillbrowser.html

Does it meet your expectation ?

Answer (score 0):

This script would work, if the browser supports jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stickyObject(position,top,stickyoffset) { //object
    this.position = position;
    this.top = top ;
    }
    //#tableheader represents your element's id
    $(document).ready(function(){ // stores original position details of element in an object
    tableheader = new stickyObject($("#tableheader").css("position"),$("#tableheader").css("top"));
    });

    function stickyMy(elem) {
    elemObj = (elem.data).replace("#","");
    if($(window).scrollTop()>offset.top-parseFloat(window[elemObj].stickyoffset)) {// checks if the user has scrolled past the top of the element we want to make sticky . 
    $(elem.data).addClass((elem.data).replace("#","") + "-sticky"); // if yes, then adds a class to the element elementid-sticky.
    $(elem.data).css("position","fixed");
    $(elem.data).css("top","0");
    }
    else {
    $(elem.data).removeClass((elem.data).replace("#","") + "-sticky");
    $(elem.data).css("position","");
    $(elem.data).css("position",window[elemObj].position);
    $(elem.data).css("top","");
    $(elem.data).css("top",window[elemObj].top);
    }
}
$(window).scroll("#tableheader",stickyMy).resize("#tableheader",stickyMy); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple no need to add custom script or js

just use **CSS** ;)

lets see
 this an example on current project , so i have this table headers 2 of them

```
<tr id="TableTitle">
        <th>302/365</th>
        <th id="secondH">Lundi 29 octobre </th>
    </tr>
```

& this is the css am using for it :

```
    #TableTitle {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;
padding: 4px;
background: #EFF0EB;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

all done by postion fixed that way it is fixed when you scroll
after that i just add some styling effects :)
important the z-index must be the most higher number on your page like that no element would pass on top of it (like jquery tabs ,or dialog...)

You **Should** know **how much** *table headers* you have & custom the width

```
#secondH {
width: 90%;
text-align: center;
}
```

& i let you custom the way you want it to look 
that was Very Simple :) you  see ?

CSS power

Answer (score 0):

Use two tables/divs fix the top position for the both for example

1st div height say 50px then 1st div top =0px, and second div top =50px and set overflow scroll for second div so that scroll appears for second div first div remains same.